# Is there any online judge for data mining

Tags: algorithm, machine-learning, data-mining

There are many Online Judges (OJ) for ACM/ICPC questions. And another Online Judge for Interview questions, named Leetcode (http://leetcode.com).

I think these OJs are very useful for us to learn algorithms. Recently, I am going to learn data mining algorithms. Is there any OJ for data mining questions?

Thank you very much.

Comment: There's [Kaggle](http://kaggle.com).

Answer (score 3):

There is [MLcomp](http://mlcomp.org/), where you can submit an algorithm and it will run it on a number of data sets to judge how well it is doing.

Plus, there is Kaggle, which hosts various classification competitions.

And of course you can do classes at Cousera. These are pretty much low level, but in order to get submission points you need to reproduce the known performance.

In particular the first also allows you to run several standard algorithms such as naive bayes and SVM and see how well they did. Obviously, your own implementation should perform similar then.

Unfortunately, both are pretty much focused on machine learning (i.e. classification and regression). There is very little in the unsupervised domain, clustering and outlier detection. On unlabeled data, things get too hard even to evaluate locally, so doing any kind of online judging is pretty much unsolved. What you can do is largely a one-class classification, or you just strip labels before running the algorithm.